# How do i install atinout on linux

Tags: linux, compiling

I am new to linux and ran into this issue. I am trying to run USSD commands and i was recommended to use `atinout`, however checking from their page, I can;t seem to find how to install it. I downloaded the zip from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/atinout/), it is `atinout-0.9.1`.

I tried to run `make` (*though I wasn't sure it could work*) and got this output:

```
gcc -o atinout -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -DVERSION=\"0.9.1\" -g  atinout.c
atinout.c: In function ‘is_final_result’:
atinout.c:141:6: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
  141 |   if (strcmp(&response[1], "K\r\n") == 0) {
      |      ^
atinout.c:145:2: note: here
  145 |  default:
      |  ^~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile:14: atinout] Error 1
```

Could someone guide me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error with GCC 9.3.0. One possible fix is to remove
`-Werror` from this line in Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror \
```

so that it looks like that:

```
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wextra \
```

It's possible when atinout was developed GCC didn't have
implicit-fallthrough warning yet (it was implemented only in 2016 in commit 81fea426da8 ) or another compiler was used to compile it.

Another fix is to try a different compiler, for example I don't get
any warnings or errors with clang 10.0.1:

```
$ make CC=clang
clang -o atinout -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -DVERSION=\"0.9.1\" -g  atinout.c
```

In both cases you'll end up with atinout in the current working directory:

```
$ ./atinout --version
atinout version 0.9.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Håkon Løvdal <hlovdal@users.sourceforge.net>
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under
certain conditions; see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html for details.
```

Comment: Thanks. this solved my issue. What if i want to run the `./atinout` command from any directory, what should i do

Comment: You have to copy atinout binary to one of directories in your $PATH.